# Python background thread does not work properly

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading, waitress

I have developed a Python application with Flaks and I'm using Waitress to serve it.
My application also runs a background thread which performs a polling in a directory to check if it contains files:

```
def polling_function(): 
    t = threading.current_thread()
    while getattr(t, "do_run", True): 
        dir_files = get_files(path)
        if dir_files: # if there are files in path file
           print('Files found')
        time.sleep(10)


# function that returns the list of files in a directory
def get_files(dir_path):
    try:
        list_of_files = [(d.stat().st_ctime, d.path) for d in scandir(dir_path) if d.is_file()]
        list_of_files = [basename(el[1]) for el in list_of_files]
        return list_of_files
    except:
        return []
```

In the main() method I start the background thread and I serve the web app. When I start Waitress, I specify `threads=8`, otherwise the application would be slow:

```
# start background thread
x = threading.Thread(target=polling_function)
x.daemon = True
x.start()

serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threads=8) 
    
x.do_run = False # to stop polling_function when the app is stopped
x.join() #  wait for all threads to finish executing before terminating
```

I'm running the code in a PC that has only 4 logic processors and I noticed that sometimes the polling function does not detect the files immediately (also if the directory contains files), and it should be called twice to detect the files.

Could such a problem be caused by the number of threads assigned to Waitress? So could my PC give less importance to the background thread?

Comment: You don't show how you start your code? Nor how you use the list of files?

Comment: Your polling function contains a 10-second sleep inside its loop.  If a file gets written while the thread is asleep, it can't possibly react.

Comment: The files get generated and put in the directory by an external resource, so the thread can detect them after the sleeping period. The problem is that sometimes it does not detect them at the first call of get_files(), even if the files are present

Comment: How can you possibly know that - you don't actually know when your code is checking - it doesn't say when it's checking. And you'd have to flush your output (or print to `stderr`) to really be sure.